Incorrect use of Bendixson-Dulac theorem?
I have the following system
$$\dot x = x(1-x)(2x+ay-b) \\
\dot y = (c(1-x)-d)y $$
where a,b,c,d are strictly positive constants with $b>2$ and $c>d$, defined on the set $F:=[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$.
Letting $f(x,y) := (\dot x, \dot y)$, I have constructed the dulac function $\varphi(x,y) := \frac{1}{x(1-x)y}$ and considered the divergence of $\varphi f$ on the interior of $F$
$$\nabla(\varphi f) = \frac{2}{y} > 0$$
Since it does not change sign for all $(x,y)\in int(F)$ the Bendixson-Dulac Theorem indicates that there can not exist any non-constant periodic orbits for the system. This however contradicts the result of the article from wich I have gotten the system. There they use the Poncaré-Bendixson theorem to show that every solution converges to a periodic orbit.
Thus I have probably used the Bendixson-Dulac Theorem incorrectly but I can not figure out what here would be incorrect.

Your proof looks correct to me. Can you include more details on the proof in the article? In particular, how do they show that the trajectories are bounded?

Thank you for your answer!
I have accessed the article through my institution and am a bit unsure on how much I would be allowed to share. In the article they show that $y$ must neccessarily be bounded and any solution starting in the interior (exluding the one unstable fixed point) can never reach the boundary of $F$ using the Grönwall-Bellman inequality.
Numerical simulations of the system also very much indicates the convergence of the orbits but I am entertaining the thought that they actually are convering to a homoclinic orbit of the saddle point (1,0). Could that be possible?

Could you share a link to or title of the article, if it is published?

My quick numerical simulations do not suggest that the the trajectories are bounded. For e.g. $a = 1, b = 3, c = 2, d = 1$, I find that after a certain time, the system goes on a series of excursions from the $x$-axis, each excursion looks approximately like a rectangle with sides almost coinciding with the lines $x=0$, $x = 1$, $y = 0$ and $y = y_n$ where $(y_n)$ is an increasing sequence. The $n$th excursion "wraps around" the $(n-1)$st excursion, i.e. is closer to the boundary $\partial F$.

Yes! That seems to be the case. Looking closer at the proof they use in the article it might not include the fact that in each cycle of the solution may wrap around the last one in this manner. This opens up alot of new questions which I will continue to explore thank you so much for your help Peter :)
If your interested to check out the article itself it can be found in this link: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S240589632300722X. The boundedness proof is question is given in Lemma 2 where I believe it might also be a typo ($\dot x \geq qx$).
Thanks again!

Your proof looks correct to me. The system does not have a limit cycle as the trajectories are not bounded.
I looked over the paper to see if I could find the error.
The paper's authors argue as follows: Let $\hat{x}$ denote the solution to $c(1-\hat{x})-d = 0$ and $\hat{y}$ denote the solution to $a \hat{y} - b = 0$. Observe that $\dot{y} < 0$ for any $x > \hat{x}$ and $y > 0$. Similarly, $\dot{x} > 0$ for any $x \in (0,1)$ and $y > \hat{y}$.
Consider a time $\bar{t}$ such that $y(\bar{t}) > \hat{y}$. The authors show that there exists a $t^{*}$ such that $x(\bar{t} + t^{*}) > \hat{x}$ and thus $\dot{y}(\bar{t} + t^{*}) < 0$.
The authors claim to show that $y(t) < y(\bar{t}) e^{c t^{*}}$ for all $t \geq \bar{t}$, but the proof seems to me to be erroneous. I see two problems:
(1) The claim that $x(t) \geq x(\bar{t}) e^{q (t - \bar{t})}$ for all $t \geq \bar{t}$ and some $q > 0$, which would imply that $x(t)$ is unbounded. This is a minor problem because the authors only use this claim to show that there exists $t^{*}$ such that $x(\bar{t} + t^{*}) > \hat{x}$, which appears to be correct.
(2) The authors seem to claim that Grönwall´s inequality $y(t) < y(\bar{t}) e^{c(t-\bar{t})}$ for all $t \geq \bar{t}$ and the fact that $\dot{y}(\bar{t} + t^{*}) < 0$ together imply that $y$ will never exceed $y(\bar{t} + t^{*}) < y(\bar{t}) e^{c t^{*}}$. This would be true if they showed that $\dot{y} < 0$ for all $t \geq \bar{t} + t^{*}$, but this is not the case.
Looking at Figure 1 in the paper, it is impossible for the outermost trajectory to converge to the purported limit cycle in the lower right corner, because it would have to cross the inner trajectories. I suspect there is a problem with the numerical solution (the system is very stiff near $(1, 0)$).

Thanks for strengthening me in my results! I will continue to explore this :)
